# PHP GET the ID from the previous page that I recently Insert it

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Process page from the previous page that I filled

```
SESSION_START();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';

    $subkat_id      = $_POST['idsubkat'];
    $namaitem       = $_POST['namaitem'];
    $status         = $_POST['status'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemtemp (`item_id`,`subkat_id`,`namaitem`,`status`)
                VALUES(NULL,'$subkat_id','$namaitem','$status')") 
                        or die(mysql_error());                  
        header("Location: newdata.php?id=".urlencode(trim($subkat_id)));
        } 

?>
```

and this is my PHP on the **newdata.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
include 'header.php';


                    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                                    $pass=$_GET['id'];
                                    $hasilitem = mysql_query("SELECT itemtemp.namaitem,itemtemp.item_id FROM itemtemp INNER JOIN subkategori WHERE itemtemp.subkat_id=subkategori.subkat_id AND itemtemp.subkat_id='$pass'") or die (mysql_error());
                                    while($arrayitem = mysql_fetch_array($hasilitem)) {
                                                    $nama=$arrayitem['namaitem'];
                                                    $id=$arrayitem['item_id'];
                                    }
                                echo "<h4>".$nama."</h4>"; 
                                }   else die ("No Item Selected ");



?>
```

this is work by showing the last result query from the database, but if there's 2 people inserting the data at the same time, the data will be mixed. can someone help me...

how to get the recently added?

Comment: You could store the value in a `$_SESSION['id']` which would be applicable to the individual, and not the system in general.

Comment: in my code how to implement it? in the previous one or in the newdata.php?

Comment: but i just inserted into the database how can i call it at the same time @Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a unique identifier to achieve this. In general MySQL is excellent at managing concurrent users but you should not rely on non-unique table data to identify a row.

Also, you should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` as the later is deprecated and has been removed in PHP 7.

Change your first page to :

```
SESSION_START();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'connection.php';

    $subkat_id      = $_POST['idsubkat'];
    $namaitem       = $_POST['namaitem'];
    $status         = $_POST['status'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO itemtemp (`item_id`,`subkat_id`,`namaitem`,`status`)
                VALUES(NULL,'$subkat_id','$namaitem','$status')") 
                        or die(mysql_error());                  
   $lastId = mysql_insert_id(); //Assuming item_id is an auto-incrementing identifier
        header("Location: newdata.php?id=".urlencode($lastId));
        }
```

Your updated **newData.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
include 'header.php';


if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $pass = $_GET['id'];
    $hasilitem = mysql_query("SELECT itemtemp.namaitem,itemtemp.item_id FROM itemtemp INNER JOIN subkategori WHERE itemtemp.subkat_id=subkategori.subkat_id AND itemtemp.item_id='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($arrayitem = mysql_fetch_array($hasilitem)) {
        $nama = $arrayitem['namaitem'];
        $id = $arrayitem['item_id'];
    }
    echo "<h4>" . $nama . "</h4>";
} else
    die("No Item Selected ");
?>
```

Comment: there is the unique identifier the idsubkat is subcategory ID

Comment: @Rizal yes but that's not unique to `itemtemp` which is what you're inserting and then selecting.